# Show different arrow images for arrow up/down in jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, image, background, jscrollpane

I need to show two different images for the arrow up and arrow down in a jscrollpane. In CSS I can set only one background for the arrows. How can I show two different images?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Do you want to show two images side-by-side? Simultaneously?  Do you want them to dynamically change?  Is there a particular event you want to tie into?  Can you give us more detail, please?

Comment: even i used jscrollpane in my gallery page http://www.art.com/gallery/id--0/poster.htm?ui=8AE965AAE3DC4FE0AD6A4B6F17E90D9C , i uses one up arrow and down arrow , is that what you want. If so let me know i can point to how to change those up and down images.

Answer (score 1):

You can see up and down arrows used on the Lozenge theme here:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/

That uses a sprite sheet of icons (from the jQuery UI themes). If you want to use two separate images then you can simply style the `.jspArrowUp` and `.jspArrowDown` classes.